# Can't login using Laravel+vue UI

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I can't login using an account that I registered in Laravel app. I'm not getting an error,login page just reload after I press login button. But if I register a new account everything works good. I get logged in immediately after I registered account and if I logout I can't loggin again. No error or something, just login page reloading and that's it. How should I debug what's wrong or maybe you guys have  any others hints?

Login controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Login blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Prisijungimas') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Vartotojo vardas') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" required autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Slaptažodis') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required >

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>                    

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Prisijungti') }}
                                </button>
                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: how would the login functionality know to use `username` instead of `email` (the default)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Just need to overwrite login controller to return username instead of email.

```
public function username(){
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

Thanks to @lagbox for the hint.